# Making an activity with rounded corners?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity

how can i make Android activity UI with rounded corners?
i got background.xml made with rounded corners, but when i start the activity with that background the corners are still white and sharp , just like in basic activity.

[image: picture of activity.]

Is there a way to make it rounded?

Comment: set transparent color to background .

Comment: "when i start the activity with that background" -- you will have better luck if you provide a [mcve] showing how you are applying this background. My guess is that the white is coming from your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with that background the corners are still white and sharp

That's most likely because you set it to white yourself. Instead of white you want it transparent: `0x00000000`. Note that's `ARGB` so **4** bytes and first one is alpha (0x00 - fully transparent, 0xFF - fully opaque).